# HP Fortify false positive Hard Coded Password - Java

Tags: java, fortify

I am having trouble figuring out a solution to a problen HP Fortify SCA is reporting. 
The issue it reports is:

> Hardcoded passwords may compromise system security in a way that
>   cannot be easily remedied.

The code looks similar to this:

```
@Configuration
public class MySpringConfig {

    private final String userName;

    private final String password;

    @Autowired
    public MySpringConfig(
            @Value("${my.userName}") final String userName,
            @Value("${my.password}") final String password) {
        this.host = host;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }
    ...
}
```

I cannot understand why Fortify would think this is a hard coded password. The password is being passed as a parameter to the constructor, and it is coming from a Spring `@Value`.

I have considered using `@FortifyNotPassword` to stop this false positive, but this is actually a password. I'd rather not use that annotation because it could then miss real issues, like logging this field's value.

Comment: To me, this code is a huge security concern.  "@Value" us super easy peezy for the developer.  If you're keeping your my.password as plaintext, it is a super concern.  if you're using something like jascrypt to ENC() the my.password, where are you keeping the decryption key?  In an environment variable?  Also a security concern.   https://nvisium.com/blog/2016/03/31/secure-password-strings.html

Answer (score 5):

Fortify thinks this is a hard-coded password because the tool is not as smart as a human!  It is one of the most frequent false positives I encounter as a code reviewer.

Fortify should not be used in an automated fashion without a human code auditor.  Fortify is there to help a code reviewer look at interesting stuff, not to replace the code reviewer.  The code reviewer needs to either suppress or filter out this issue manually.

If you want a more automated solution, Fortify is not the right tool because it brings up too many false positives.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, it is the fact that Fortify is just not that smart. It turns out that the complaint was tied to the fact that "password" appeared in the String `@Value("${my.password}")`. Simply changing it to `@Value("${my.value}")` made the error go away.

There was also a relation to the fact that it was stored in a field. In the end, I rearranged the class more like this and the violation went away:

```
@Configuration
public class MySpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean(
            @Value("${my.userName}") final String userName,
            @Value("${my.password}") final String password) {
        return new MyBeanThatNeedsUserCredentials(userName, password);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortify has different analyzers. In this case, it looks like the semantic analyzer was used. It's simply a grep for the word "password". So you can evaluate this case to a false positive. The semantic analyzer tends to be very noisy.

If you use the AuditWorkbench, under the Summary tab (after you click on a finding) you can see the which engine was used to find the issue. It's on the right side of the panel.